How to Deploy and Distribute Office Add-in (JavaScript) to Multiple Users After Migrating from .NET ADX COM Add-in?
We have recently migrated our Office add-in application from a .NET ADX COM add-in to a JavaScript-based Office add-in due to Microsoft's discontinuation of support for .NET ADX COM add-ins. Our new add-in is developed using web technologies such as HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. However, we are now facing challenges in deploying and distributing this new JavaScript-based add-in to multiple users efficiently.
Previously, we used ClickOnce deployment for our .NET ADX COM add-in, which was straightforward for our users. Now, with the move to JavaScript, we need guidance on the best practices and steps to deploy and distribute this Office add-in to our clients.
Not for Office 365: Note that this deployment is not targeted for Office 365 environments.
Specifically, I need way on:
Methods to automate the deployment process to make it seamless for our clients.
Automating the setup of trust and installation steps for users, considering they find manual configuration lengthy.
We tested the installation process by manually configuring the Trust Center settings in Excel
Users can install the add-in by opening Excel, navigating to File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings > Trusted Add-in Catalogs, and adding the URL of our IIS server where the manifest is hosted.
Expectation : Automated Deployment: Methods or tools to automate the deployment of our JavaScript-based Office add-in to multiple users.
Any insights, examples, or best practices on deploying and distributing Office add-ins developed with JavaScript in non-Office 365 environments would be greatly appreciated.
